# Angular: Reactive nested form does not update

Tags: angular

I have a problem with my nested reactive form: it is not reactive.
I have several ngfor, but when the control is updated, nothing changes in the browser. so first here is the code:

```
   <form [formgroup]="newRequest" >
        <div formarrayname="roundway">
          <div *ngfor="let item of newRequest.controls['roundway'] | arraypipe; let i=index">
            <div [formgroupname]="i" >
              <h4 *ngif="roundtrip">{{i===0 ? 'Aller' : 'Retour' }}</h4>
              ***mat-form-fields***
              <div formarrayname="viaOut" *ngif="viaOut">
                <div *ngfor="let item of newRequest.controls.roundway.controls[i].controls.viaOut | arraypipe; let j=index">
                  ***mat-form-fields***
                </div>
                <button mat-icon-button="" type="button" (click)="removeViaOut()" [disabled]="viaOut<2" fxflexalign="center">
                  <mat-icon matprefix="">remove</mat-icon>
                </button>
                <button mat-icon-button="" type="button" (click)="addViaOut()" [disabled]="viaOut>2" fxflexalign="center">
                  <mat-icon matprefix="">add</mat-icon>
                </button>
              </div>
              <!--Vols -->
              <div formarrayname="flights" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutalign="start center" fxlayoutwrap="">
                <div *ngfor="let item of newRequest.controls.roundway.controls[i].controls.flights | arraypipe; let k=index" fxlayout="row" fxlayoutgap="30px">
                  <div fxlayoutalign="start center" fxlayoutgap="30px" fxlayoutwrap="" [formgroupname]="k">
                    <h5 *ngif="viaOut>=1">Vol n°{{k+1}}</h5>

                    ***mat-form-fields***
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

And my typescript

```
    export class NouvelledemandeComponent implements OnInit {
  public newRequest: FormGroup;

  // Minimal date
  minDate = new Date();

  // Conditions for details display
  daterange = false;
  differentflights = false;
  details = false;
  viaIn = 0;
  viaOut = 0;
  roundtrip = false;

  // Form controllers
  classFC: FormControl = new FormControl();


  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newRequest = this._fb.group({
      roundway: this._fb.array([
        this.initRoundway()
    ])
    });
  }

  initFlights() {
      return this._fb.group({
          class: ['', Validators.required],
          flightNb: [''],
          timeMin: [''],
          timeMax : ['']
      });
  }


  addFlight() {
    const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.get('roundway.0.flights');
      control1.push(this.initFlights());
}

  removeFlight() {
    const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.get('roundway.0.flights');
      control1.removeAt(control1.length - 1);
  }


  addViaOut() {
    const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.get('roundway.0.viaOut');
    control1.push(new FormControl(null));
    this.viaOut++;
    this.addFlight();
  }

  removeViaOut(i: number) {
    const control1 = <FormArray>this.newRequest.get('roundway.0.viaOut');
    control1.removeAt(control1.length - 1);
    this.viaOut--;
    this.removeFlight();
  }

  addViaIn() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.newRequest.get('roundway.0.viaIn');
    control.push(new FormControl(null));
    this.viaIn++;
  }

  removeViaIn(i: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.newRequest.controls['viaIn'];
    control.removeAt(control.length - 1);
    this.viaIn--;
  }



initRoundway() {
      return this._fb.group({
        daterangeOutFrom: [],
        daterangeOutTo: [],
        viaOut: this._fb.array([]),
        viaIn: this._fb.array([]),
        flights: this._fb.array([
          this.initFlights()
      ])
      });
  }



}
```

So my problem is that whenever toggleVia is triggered, a via and a flight are added (I can see with console.log that my flights array and my viaout array are updated), but it does not appear on the browser.
Seems like my ngfor runs once, when the component is launched, then that's all; even if the array is updated nothing happens.

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is not a *minimal* reproduction of your issue, please strip it down to the minimal code to reproduce the problem you are facing :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to reduce it but is was not enough; I reduced it more, please take a look :)

Comment: First of all, angular directives are case-sensitive `formgroup` and `formgroupname` and `ngif`

Comment: Where is the `initRoundway` method?

Comment: @yurzui Yes but it seems to me that my directives are ok. Also, I added my initroundway method at the end of my typescript. I reduced my code too much sorry :/

Comment: @ManonIngrassia Still too much code, and some issues when even trying to copy paste your template to editor, which I tried. Also is not reproducable since you are apparently using a pipe also. Please create a working demo which showcases the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found the problem. I had my ngFor like this:

```
<div *ngfor="let item of newRequest.controls['roundway'] | arraypipe; let i=index">
```

The problem was here: it should be `<div *ngfor="let item of newRequest.controls.roundway.controls; let i=index">`

I had the same problem with all my ngFor, so whenever the controls of an array changed, it didn't update the view because the ngFor wasn't set on the controls.
Moreover, the pipe kind of "broke" this all; it was needed before, but now that it is set on controls, which is clearly an array, it is useless.
Finally, the path was not correctly wrote.